# Insert dynamic content into posts

Tags: plugins, php, array

I'm currently using this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/automatic-featured-image-posts/  which creates batches of posts from uploaded images

I'm also using this code here to generate the default content for every new post

```
add_filter( 'afip_new_post_content', 'diww_default_post_content' );
function diww_default_post_content() {
  $content = "<iframe src=></iframe>";
  return $content;
}
```

Now I have a php array of URL's which I want to insert into the src for each post. Is it possible via some loop or sequential manner insert each URL into each post sequentially?

e.g.

- URL[0] -> Post[0]
- URL[1] -> Post[1]
- URL[2] -> Post[2]

and so on.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do. Assign a single image to each post in a loop (until you run out of either posts or images, I assume)? Why do you start talking about images and end by talking about URLS and post? What is the connection?

Comment: I believe what he's trying to do is to "pull" content from the provided urls - thus the "dynamic content" in the question.

But yeah, leading off with the image plugin was sort of confusing..

Comment: quick question. How are you getting the urls?

Comment: @WPThemes yea that's what I'm trying to do. Basically, each image upload creates automatically a new post associated with that image. In the contents section I want to place an iframe with an URL src. Since I have hundreds of images and I don't want to manually add hundreds of URL's I'm looking for an automatic solution. The URL's I have pulled from google and stored in a php array

Comment: And each new post will use only one URL?

Comment: yep, each new post will use one unique URL, any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: each URL will need to be pushed sequentially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you upload a new image, the `afip_new_post_content` filter is called which can be used to change the post content before creation - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/automatic-featured-image-posts/

Assuming you have a list of URLs stored somewhere - like in the database - you need a function that would get a url from this list, then delete the url you used from that list so it doesn't get used again.

```
function get_one_url(){
    /**
     * your urls would be stored somewhere I suppose. Everytime you get a url,
     * the number of URLs would decrease by one.
     */

    //this is just a sample. you could probably build this using a database call.
    $list_of_urls = array(
        "http://url1.com",
        "http://url2",
        "http://url3"
    );

    //get the first url off the list and save it to the variable $url
    $url = array_shift( $list_of_urls );

    //save new list to database. This is just a sample.
    save_my_list( $list_of_urls );

    return $url;
}


add_filter( 'afip_new_post_content', 'diww_default_post_content' );
function diww_default_post_content() {
    $url = get_one_url();
    $content = "<iframe src={$url}></iframe>";
    return $content;
}

?>
```

Comment: that code looks pretty much like what I need! I'm going to have a go at it now, and report back asap! Thanks

Comment: omg, thank you it works your code. Thanks so much for the help!  :) you rock

Comment: you're welcome.. glad it worked for you :)

Comment: If I could up vote your answer I would but I don't have enough points yet  :p